# how to make all strings length into same size in column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am creating excel file from referring another excel so the excel file which I created has 3 columns one is Serial number,class and student name so in student name column all names length are different but I want all names length are same means all names are displayed in proper alignment.I am using pandas module for excel creation.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELTUS.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply the len function .

```
df['student name_length'] = df['student name'].apply(len)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ljust` like so:

```
df.name.str.ljust(20)
```

`20` can be replaced by the longest name.